# How to pass data to the $slots in child component?

Tags: vue.js

I have two components

1. Navigation
2. Alert

Alert is Navigation's child

1. Navigation code

   ```
   <template>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
         <base-alert :icon="`fa fa-facebook`"></base-alert>
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
      data() {
        return {
           error: 'This is error'
        }
      }
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Base alert code

   ```
   <slot>
       <span v-if="icon" class="alert-inner--icon">
         <i :class="icon"></i>
       </span>
       <span v-if="$slots.text" class="alert-inner--text">
         <slot name="text"></slot>
       </span>
    </slot>
   ```

Currently this is what I got

[image]

My problem right now how do i pass the error data to the base-alert $slots.text?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add  `<template slot="text">{{ error }}</template>` as below. Where text is the name of slot you have mentioned in Base Alert

1. Navigation Code

```
<template>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <base-alert :icon="`fa fa-facebook`">
      <template slot="text">{{ error }}</template>
    </base-alert>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import baseAlert from "./base-alert";
export default {
   components: { baseAlert },
   data() {
     return {
       error: "This is error"
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

2. Base Alert

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot>
      <span v-if="icon" class="alert-inner--icon">
        <i :class="icon"></i>
      </span>
      <span v-if="$slots.text" class="alert-inner--text">
        <slot name="text"></slot>
      </span>
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "base-alert",
  props: ["icon"]
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score -1):

Pass your error message down as a prop to the child.

1. Navigation code

   ```
   <template>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
         <base-alert :error="error" :icon="`fa fa-facebook`"></base-alert>
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
      data() {
        return {
           error: 'This is error'
        }
      }
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Base alert code

   ```
   <slot>
       <span v-if="icon" class="alert-inner--icon">
         <i :class="icon"></i>
       </span>
       <span v-if="error" class="alert-inner--text">
         <div>{{ error }}</div>
       </span>
    </slot>
   ```